# Can react-leaflet handle indoor maps levels?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, maps, react-leaflet

I'm building an react map for indoor location, I need to handle the levels of the building. Can react-leaflet handle this?, I am a newbie in Maps.
This is an example built in ruby about What I am talking about:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi @kboul , How you created the Custom map ?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use 1 "base" layer per building level / floor, and let the user switch between them.